# Factorization of determinant?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

I'm given the determinant of some matrix:

$$ det\begin{pmatrix} 
1 + x & 1 + x + x^2 & 1 + x + x^2 + x^3 \\
1 + y & 1 + y + y^2 & 1 + y + y^2 + y^3 \\
1 + z & 1 + z + z^2 & 1 + z + z^2 + z^3 \\
\end{pmatrix} $$

We are asked to write this determinant with as many factors as possible. It also gives a hint the the maximum number of factors here is 4.

I'm asking myself how I can easily compute this instead of calculating the determinant by hand. Is there some trick that makes this more easy than it seems? To me at least I don't see the usefulness of it.

Comment: I'd think in terms of roots of unity: $x^n-1 = (x-1)(x^{n-1}+\ldots+x+1)$

Comment: Since we get $0$ if $x=y$, $(x-y)$ will be a factor.

Comment: @Berci. Continuing with your good argument, the obvious factors are $(x-y)$ , $(x-z)$, $(y-z)$.